# Manjaro: SSD not recognized in BIOS after installation

Tags: boot, uefi, ssd, manjaro, bios

I've installed Manjaro 17.11.1 on my ASUS UX31A. Before there was ElementaryOS running on it without a problem.

When I startup the system after installation the laptop enters BIOS directly. There's no boot order as it seems like there's no boot loader detected at all. I tried various settings in the BIOS and installed the system like 10times now:

- With CMS (Asus legacy BIOS?) enabled
- With CMS (Asus legacy BIOS?) disabled
- Installing from DVD
- Installing from USB stick
- Trying to [restore the Bootload manually](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Restore_the_GRUB_Bootloader)

[image: Partions on setup]
[image: BIOS after installation]
[image: Partions after installation]

Comment: If the boot "url" stored in the UEFI firmware doesn't work, you can put this boot loader in a generic location/name that should be autodetected,that's exactly how you can boot a live USB.You just have to find the file grubx64.efi which is somewhere in the EFI partition and do a copy as EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi (so it would be probably named in the end /boot/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi or /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi depending on your layout).You can use any live USB distribution for this.some informations ("Fallback"): https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/

Comment: In mount /dev/sda1 /boot I find:

/boot/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi

It seems to be where it's supposed to be ...

Comment: Indeed. that was the only thing I thought about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- boot from the USB drive (with the Manjaro installation on it)
- connect to WiFi (no need if you're already in your LAN)
- open a shell
- open gparted and check which is the boot partition (in my case /dev/sda1)
- install efibootmgr: `sudo pacman -Sy efibootmgr`
- Now install your EFI image: `sudo efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda1 --part 1 --label "Manjaro SSD"`

`--disk`: must point to your boot Partition
`--part`: number of the partition (I just guessed it's 1)
`--label`: text that will be shown in the boot loader on startup (choose whatever you want)
`--loader`: that's the EFI image. The path has to be relative to /boot/efi (in my case it's at /boot/efi/EFI/Manajaro/grubx64.efi). And yes: you need to use the windows backslashes!

If you have no clue where to finde the EFI image: Mount the boot partition and have a look (I used gparted again to unmount it before using efibootmgr. Don't know if it's necessary):
`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /boot`